# How to get a SelectedValue @Html.DropDownList and INSERT into Database in Razor C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I have a dropdownlist, which I have filled with items from a database. The dropdownlist displays the item name however the value when selected is the ID of the item and not the name.

I want to insert this a new record on a different table but I am getting the following error and I have attempted to research the problem:

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'customerID' does not exist in the current context

```
@{
Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Add Server";

var db = Database.Open("BackupMonitoringAppV2") ;
var listcustomers = "SELECT CustomerName, CustomerID from Customers";

List<SelectListItem> customerdropdowndata = new List<SelectListItem>();
bool isSelected = false;
foreach(var item in db.Query(listcustomers)){   
    customerdropdowndata.Add(new SelectListItem
    {

        Text = item.CustomerName,
        Value = item.CustomerID.ToString(), 
        Selected = isSelected
    });
}

            ///Need to resolve the issue with request form adding to database.

 var servername = "";


 if(IsPost){
    customerID = Request.Form["Customers"];
    servername = Request.Form["ServerName"];

    var db2 = Database.Open("BackupMonitoringAppV2");
    var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Servers (CustomersID, Servername,) Values(@0, @1)";
    db.Execute(insertCommand, customerID, servername);
    Response.Redirect("~/Dashboard/Servers");

}
```

### HTML

```html
<form role="form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    
      @Html.DropDownList("Customers", customerdropdowndata)
  </div>
  
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="CustomerName">Server Name</label>
      
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customername" value="@Request.Form["ServerName"]" />
  </div>
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="buttonSubmit">Add Server</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't process all that in the view, that's what the controller is for. Put your code for the database inserting inside your POST method on the controller. Then you can collect the submitted for elements.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using ASP.NET web pages with Web Matrix to do this.